# advanced searchpage

Tags: visualforce

I have two objects: Course and University (lookup relationship). Now I have to create a search page in which I enter values in multiple fields and click on "Search". Then it should query & display the fields I filled in and display them in a page block table.

```
<apex:page controller="mycontroller1">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="search">
                  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel >Course Name</apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:inputtext value="{!op.name}"/>
                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>       
                        <apex:inputField value="{!op.University__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!op.Type__c}"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!op.Department__c}"/>   
              <apex:inputField value="{!op.Intake_season__c}"/>    
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
                  <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                      <apex:commandButton value="search" action="{!dosearch}"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      </apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:PageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opp}" var="a">
             <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.Type__c}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.University__r.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.University__r.Website__c}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.University__r.Number_of_students__c}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!a.University__r.University_or_Clz_Picture__c}"/>

          </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:PageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class mycontroller1 {

    public PageReference dosearch() {
    String sqlquery='select id,name,University__c,Type__c,Intake_season__c,University__r.Name,University__r.Website__c,University__r.Number_of_students__c,University__r.University_or_Clz_Picture__c  from Course__c where name like '+'\'%'+ + '%\'';
           opp=Database.query(sqlquery);
        return null;
    }

public Course__c op{get;set;}
public list<Course__c> opp{get;set;}
public mycontroller1(){
opp=[select id,name,University__c,Type__c,Intake_season__c,University__r.Name,University__r.Website__c,University__r.Number_of_students__c,University__r.University_or_Clz_Picture__c from Course__c ];
}
}
```

Comment: Sravanthi, what is your question ?